# hiding a part of URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to hide a part of URL after a rewrite.

below is the rewrite rule I'm using in my .htaccess and this basically executes http://example.com/index.php-someextrainfohere when someone tries to access abc.com . what I'd like to achieve is that, I'd like to hide "-someextrainfohere" part after this rewrite. from what I feel, I am unable to make this with a second rewrite rule. any idea how can I go ahead with this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php-someextrainfohere
```

thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hide" - do you want the information to still be available to your application?

Comment: Hi Pekka, I am trying to have just http://xyz.com on browser's address bar, without all other stuff.

Comment: I don't follow. Why are you rewriting the URL with the extra info in the first place if you want it gone?

Comment: Well, there is a core website where my main script is hosted. And I have multiple sub-sites those acting like proxies to this core site. When someone tries to access through a sub-site, I am trying to forward it to core site using some extra variables which are allowing me to track some data(this is different for each sub-site) and that's what I don't want to expose to my visitors.

Comment: Provide some examples of original URI on a sub-site then the redirected URI on the core site.

Comment: Hi anuhava, here's an example; I want http://xyz.com/index.php?&syssrc=abc to be executed but I'm trying to expose this as http://xyz.com/index.php or http://xyz.com to visitor. I don't want them to be able to see syssrc=abc part.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, there is a core website where my main script is hosted. And I have multiple sub-sites those acting like proxies to this core site. When someone tries to access through a sub-site, I am trying to forward it to core site using some extra variables which are allowing me to track some data(this is different for each sub-site) and that's what I don't want to expose to my visitors.

In that case, you will have to do a header redirect anyway, and you could do that in your PHP script after you parse the additional information.

In index.php:

```
(parse the extra info)

header("location: http://www.xyz.com");
die();
```

you could theoretically also use the HTTP_REFERER variable instead of adding the extra info, but it's not 100% reliable as it can be turned off on client side.

Comment: Thanks Pekka! However, the script is encrypted and I'm not good with php either.

Comment: @compixtr I see - I *think* this is the only way, though. If you rewrite the URL in .htaccess, the information will be lost to the script.

Comment: Thanks Pekka! I'll keep researching about this a bit more.